# Package not found: com.android.chrome

Tags: android, android-webview, chromium

I have seen lots of crashes in the app with the message used as title here. Almost all of the crashes are on OnePlus devices and most of them are on the version of Oxygen OS forked from Android Oreo. Has anyone else seen this? The following is the stack trace:

```
 java.lang.RuntimeException: Package not found: com.android.chrome
    at android.webkit.WebViewDelegate.getPackageId(WebViewDelegate.java:164)
    at com.android.webview.chromium.ig.L(WebViewDelegateFactory.java:16)
    at com.android.webview.chromium.WebViewChromiumFactoryProvider.h(WebViewChromiumFactoryProvider.java:177)
    at com.android.webview.chromium.se.run(WebViewChromiumFactoryProvider.java:5)
    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:789)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:98)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:164)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6809)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at com.android.internal.os.Zygote$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(Zygote.java:240)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:767)
```

**Edit: 18th Feb, 2018:**

We received our team's One Plus 5T(OnePlus A5010) a few weeks back and did not see any issue while running our app. The device came preloaded with the OxygenOS fork of Android 7.0. However, today the device received the Android 8.0.0(OxygenOS 5.0.3) update notification and after successfully installing the update, our app is crashing with the same stack trace. This crash is horribly affecting our user base. Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Is chrome installed?  Or does it have an alternative browser?

Comment: Still waiting on the ordered OnePlus device to arrive so can't answer device related questions. But the crash has happened around 2500 times in around 480 users with OnePlus devices.

Comment: maybe chrome need special permission which you didn't permit that, try to accept all permission on app manager for chrome

Comment: no more investigation yet?

Comment: Probably this thread may be of interest https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=506369

Comment: @TarunLalwani The issue does not occur during webview updates. The crashes happen randomly

Comment: @JayeshElamgodil did you resolve the issue? i am having the same issue for about 650 User in the last 7 Days.

Comment: @Pfennigbaum Nope, still same.

Comment: The issue on OnePlus forum: https://forums.oneplus.com/threads/package-not-found-com-android-chrome.722221

Comment: @Jayesh any progress on this? I'm struggling with the same issue, I would be glad to discuss it again with you. Thx.

Answer (score 6):

WebView is now controlled by Chrome from Nougat.
[Reference](https://gadgets.ndtv.com/apps/news/google-chrome-to-replace-webview-in-android-70-nougat-863667)

The solution that worked for me was commenting these lines in AndroidManifest.xml

```
<meta-data android:name="preloaded_fonts" 
           android:resource="@array/preloaded_fonts" />
```

As suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47587481/3486601)

Comment: We don't have this line in our manifest file. Also, we don't see any issues when the app opens a webview.

Comment: Can you let me know exactly when crash is happening ?

Comment: There are no obvious ways to reproduce this crash. Sometimes, it happens during app launch and other times it happens randomly while interacting with the app. But it does not happen when the webView is used.

Answer (score 1):

Do you have multiple profiles on your device?

There is a [known issue](https://support.google.com/work/android/answer/7506908?hl=en) on the Google (Android Enterprise) support forums relating to WebView. It seems like the solution may well apply to your problem.

**Summary:**

> A feature was added in Android Nougat to set the Chrome WebView as the default WebView and disable the Android System WebView app by default

**This is a problem when:**

- Device needs to be on Android Oreo (Android 8.0)
- More than one user on device (For example, there’s a work profile and personal profile)
- Chrome is not enabled for at least one user on the device. Note: Chrome is disabled in the work profile by default.
- Chrome has been updated on the device and the device has *[not?]* restarted since Chrome updated.
- The Android System WebView app has not been updated via Google Play.

**What you need to do:**

Enable Chrome for each user on the device **Or** Wait for the Android System WebView app to update to its latest version (updates occur automatically within 24 hours provided the device has a WiFi connection)

Comment: Is it possible the One Plus has any hidden profiles then? at least for your own profile it may be worth checking neither the chrome webview or standard android one are disabled (I'd suggest doing it via packagemanager rather than relying on what the UI shows)

Comment: Nope there is no hidden profile and also neither chrome nor the standard webview are disabled.

Answer (score 1):

Do you happen to use Facebook Audience Network SDK in your app?
Ran into the same crash and it seems that the crash is directly related to FAN SDK (using 4.27.1). When the app tries to show an Ad from FAN it crashes sometimes (only on OnePlus devices so far).

This is not 100% confirmed yet but might help.

Edit: It might be related to any other Ad network SDK, many of these use WebView to show the Ad. In this case, FAN SDK is invoked only as a fallback if there is something wrong with AdMob. It can easily happen that it'd crash AdMob as well but that SDK handles it while FAN doesn't.

Comment: The app does not use FAN. The app does not use any kind of ad network either.